# Creating JSON JFORM request

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to use [JSON Form Playground](http://ulion.github.io/jsonform/playground/?example=schema-morecomplex) for dynamically creating html forms from JSON, which will allow them to edit already existing requests. I have the requests persisted somewhere in db, and I have the mapping request class. I want to convert the json request into JSON Form request format.

Ex - Persisted Request

```
{"message":"My message","author":{"name":"author name","gender":"male","magic":36}}
```

Mapping class

```
public class DummyRequest
{
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("author")
    private Author author;

    // constructors, getters and setters ommitted 
    public static class Author
    {
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;

        @SerializedName("gender")
        private Gender gender;

        @SerializedName("magic")
        private Integer magic;
    }

    public static enum Gender
    {
        male, female, alien
    }
}
```

I created the above request, which is persisted as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DummyRequest dummyRequest = new DummyRequest();
        dummyRequest.setMessage("My message");
        DummyRequest.Author author = new DummyRequest.Author("author name", DummyRequest.Gender.male, 36);
        dummyRequest.setAuthor(author );
        String dummyRequestJson = new Gson().toJson(dummyRequest);
        System.out.println(dummyRequestJson);
    }
```

Now from the above, I want to create a JSON in the following format:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Message",
      "default": "My message"
    },
    "author": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Author",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Name"
        },
        "gender": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Gender",
          "enum": [ "male", "female", "alien" ]
        },
        "magic": {
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "Magic number",
          "default": 42
        }
      },
      "default": {"name": "Author name", "gender": "alien", "magic": 36}
    }
  }
}
```

This seems rather complicated and tedious if I approach the brute force way. Can some one guide me on how to proceed. I don't want to create any new request classes in Java.

Comment: Are you asking for optimising this or are you open to using GSON library

Comment: I am open to using gson library.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/gson

You can use models inside models to achieve what you need.

ALL you need to do is serialise data using gson as follows

```
     @SerializedName("schema")
       private Schema schema;
```

And your Schema object will be like

```
       @SerializedName("message")
       private Message message;
       @SerializedName("author")
       private Author author;
           -- and so on
```

use the below code to get object from json

```
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    Model yourModel=gson.fromJson(<your json object as string>);
```

use below code to get json string from object

```
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String string=gson.toJson(yourObject,YourObject.class);
```

Comment: Where are you setting "type", "title", "default" for each field  ?

Comment: That will be a seperate model. You just set up all the models once and after that its easy throughout the app